# Solr5 + SolrJ: calling SolrClient.close() causes thread pool to shutdown

Tags: java, spring, solr, solrj

**TL;DR** - how are connections supposed to be handled with SolrJ connecting to a SolrCloud or standalone Solr instance?

Given the following Spring-bean config for the Apache SolrJ clint:

```
 <!-- SolrCloud client connector overrides the default standalone Solr instance connector -->
        <bean id="SolrClient" class="org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient">
            <constructor-arg index="0" value="${solr.zkHosts}"/>
            <property name="defaultCollection" value="${solr.collection}"/>
        </bean>
```

I stand up a SolrClient connection from a singleton config class like this:

```
SolrClient solrClient = config.getSolrClient();
solrClient.ping();
```

I then called

```
finally{
   if(solrClient == null){
       solrClient.close();
   }
}
```

When I try to call the method again I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection pool shut down
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.LBHttpSolrClient.doRequest(LBHttpSolrClient.java:410)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.LBHttpSolrClient.request(LBHttpSolrClient.java:325)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient.sendRequest(CloudSolrClient.java:1100)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient.requestWithRetryOnStaleState(CloudSolrClient.java:871)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient.request(CloudSolrClient.java:807)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:150)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.ping(SolrClient.java:927)
```

From reading the SolrJ docs, close() does the following:

[SolrJ 5.4.0 JavaDocs](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/5_4_0/solr-solrj/index.html)

```
Closes this stream and releases any system resources associated with it.
```

It appears that calling close on the connection literally closes the threadpool as well, preventing future connections... what is the correct way of handling multiple connections to Solr with SolrJ?

Comment: I know you are using Singleton instance, but how frequently you are calling `config.getSolrClient();` to the singleton instance and `finally` block?

Comment: every request - this sits behind a Spring @Controller endpoint. I thought i needed to close the client at the end of each request but apparently solrClient.close() has some unintended consequences...

Comment: Yes. That is the issue. You should not close the solr connection after each request, close only when work is completed or application is shutting down.

Comment: Have the situation where I need to do some refactoring and I'm seeing #close called after each request - the CloudSolrClient is also created at each request. I've came across this answer and I think it does adds up to @YoungHobbit's answer. Link: http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/SolrClient-reuse-the-client-or-just-call-close-td4238280.html